# another data date value null when grab html

Tags: php, html, mysql

here's my problem, i tried grab date and change to date format from special character in 2 table. it successful. **but 1 table the date return 0000-00-00 00:00:00, another table success**. here's code,table and output below.

Table 1

```
<TABLE class="tab1" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
summary="">
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;Start RIP Job</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Send Date:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;1/9/2017 1:15 PM&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RIP Start Date and Time:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;13:21:22 09/01/2017&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RIP End Date and Time:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;13:21:33 09/01/2017&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RIP Duration:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;11 seconds&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;End RIP Job</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Table 2

```
<TABLE class="tab1" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
summary="">
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;Start RIP Job</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Printer:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RunJiang Flora 3204P&nbsp; 
&nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Send Date:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;9/29/2017 10:09 PM&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RIP Start Date and Time:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;22:09:49 29/09/2017&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RIP End Date and Time:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;22:10:13 29/09/2017&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RIP Duration:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;24 seconds&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;End RIP Job</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

CODE :

```
$source=file_get_contents("C://xampp/htdocs/Champion/machine-logs/LogPrinting04/nulldate.HTML");
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($source);
// print_r($dom);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $textList = $xp->query("//table[//th[contains(text(),'')]]");
    foreach ( $textList as $text )  {
     $enddate = $xp->evaluate(
                "string(descendant::tr[th[contains(text(),'RIP End Date and Time') or contains(text(),'Output End Date And Time')]]/td/text())",
                $text);
        $date = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z \/:\-]/", "", $enddate);
        $xtime = strtotime($date);
        $tes = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$xtime);
        echo "enddate=".$tes.PHP_EOL;
        }
```

OUTPUT :

table 1 : 2017-09-01 13:21:33

table 2 : 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

`'29'` is not a valid month value.

Look at the one that is returning a value. Notice that it's returning September 1, not January 9.

```
  13:21:33 09/01/2017    ->  2017-09-01 13:21:33
           mm dd yyyy        yyyy mm dd
```

Then look at the one that is returning zeros.

```
  22:10:13 29/09/2017    
           mm dd yyyy
```

`29` is not a valid value for month. (If we're expecting this input to be a representation of September 29, then we're also probably expecting the first one to be a representation of January 1.)

Comment: quote: "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed;"   http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php